# Laravel Spatie Roles and permissions - error on Update

Tags: laravel, roles, laravel-permission

I need help for my Laravel application.

I use spatie roles and permissions.

When i create the user, assign roles is no problem. When i will update the same user, there is the following error:

> [2019-12-06 08:44:36] local.ERROR: The given role or permission should use guard `` instead of `web`. {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Spatie\\Permission\\Exceptions\\GuardDoesNotMatch(code: 0): The given role or permission should use guard `` instead of `web`. at /home/vagrant/code/test/vendor/spatie/laravel-permission/src/Exceptions/GuardDoesNotMatch.php:12)

```
public function store(StoreUserRequest $request)
{
    $user = $this->repo->create( $request->all());

    $user->assignRole($request->roles);

    return $user;
}

public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request, User $user)
{
    $user = $this->repo->update($user, $request->all());

    $user->assignRole($request->roles);

    return $user;
}
```

I added `protected $guard_name = 'web';` to the User Model but still the same problem.

What is wrong? Is there a problme with the userId?

Comment: this could be good if you try delete tbl ``models_has_roles`` then ``assignRole()`` again to your user ``DB::table('model_has_roles')->where('model_id',$id)->delete();`` and assign role again ``$user->assignRole($request->input('roles'));``

Answer (score 3):

On update method use `syncRoles` instead of `assignRole`

Comment: Do you have UseRoles in User?

Comment: I think the problem is the type of array. I'm sending `"roles":["User","Admin"]` to the backend. But the backend creates an array `array (
  0 => 'User',
  1 => 'Admin',
)  `

Comment: Sorry, it was an error from my side. At the beginning, i copied the User Model from App\User to App\Models\User. I forgot to delete the old one. In my controller, I imported App\User which was wrong!

Comment: Great to hear that

Comment: thanks, it worked using syncRoles instead assignRole!

Answer (score 1):

When you assign role for a user the model path `App\User` insert into table `model_has_roles` if you change the model folders spatie give you an error. I think this code may help you more.
don't missing add `HasRoles`

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    use Notifiable, HasRoles;
    ...
}
```

make sure you import `use App\User;`
**UserController**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id,
            'password' => 'same:confirm-password',
            'roles' => 'required'
        ]);


        $input = $request->all();
        if(!empty($input['password'])){ 
            $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);
        }else{
            $input = array_except($input,array('password'));    
        }


        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->update($input);
        DB::table('model_has_roles')->where('model_id',$id)->delete();


        $user->assignRole($request->input('roles'));


        return redirect()->route('users.index')
                        ->with('success','User updated successfully');
    }
```